# How to make SurfaceView with transparent background?

Tags: android, surfaceview

I have simple layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/backgroundtimer"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

    <com.fmech.zenclock.surface.ZenClockSurface
        android:id="@+id/zenClockSurface1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And a have ZenClockSurface class

```
package com.fmech.zenclock.surface;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class ZenClockSurface extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

    private DrawClock drawClock;

    public ZenClockSurface(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        this.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
    }

    public ZenClockSurface(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
    }

    public ZenClockSurface(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        //this.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
        drawClock = new DrawClock(getHolder(), getResources());
        drawClock.setRunning(true);
        drawClock.start();

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        boolean retry = true;
        // завершаем работу потока
        drawClock.setRunning(false);
        while (retry) {
            try {
                drawClock.join();
                retry = false;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }

    }

    class DrawClock extends Thread{
        private boolean runFlag = false;
        private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
        private Bitmap picture;
        private Matrix matrix;
        private long prevTime;
        private Paint painter;

        public DrawClock(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, Resources resources){
            this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;

            this.surfaceHolder.setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
            picture = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.ic_launcher);

            matrix = new Matrix();
            this.painter=new Paint();
            this.painter.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        }

        public void setRunning(boolean run) {
            runFlag = run;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Canvas canvas;
            while (runFlag) {

                    matrix.preRotate(1.0f, picture.getWidth() / 2, picture.getHeight() / 2);
                canvas = null;
                try {
                    //surfaceHolder.getSurface().setAlpha(0.5f);
                    canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                    synchronized (surfaceHolder) {

                        canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

                        canvas.drawBitmap(picture, matrix, this.painter);
                    }
                } 
                finally {
                    if (canvas != null) {
                        surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And code of activity

```
package com.fmech.zenclock.surface;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class ZenClockSurfaceActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


    }
}
```

I want what background color of android picture was tranparent but i get black background.

I have background on RelativeLayout with some picture bu SurfaceView rotate Android icon with no transparent.

How i can do transparent?

Comment: I forgot to add this.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);in both of the constructor

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yeah, i did it i solve problem

**Activity code**

```
package com.fmech.zenclock.surface;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class ZenClockSurfaceActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ZenClockSurface sfvTrack = (ZenClockSurface)findViewById(R.id.zenClockSurface1);
        sfvTrack.setZOrderOnTop(true);    // necessary
        SurfaceHolder sfhTrack = sfvTrack.getHolder();
        sfhTrack.setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    }
}
```

**Surface Code**

```
package com.fmech.zenclock.surface;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.graphics.Region;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.Surface.OutOfResourcesException;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class ZenClockSurface extends SurfaceView implements
        SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private DrawClock drawClock;

    public ZenClockSurface(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
    }

    public ZenClockSurface(Context context) {
        super(context);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
    }

    public ZenClockSurface(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        drawClock = new DrawClock(getHolder(), getResources());
        drawClock.setRunning(true);
        drawClock.start();

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        boolean retry = true;
        drawClock.setRunning(false);
        while (retry) {
            try {
                drawClock.join();
                retry = false;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }

    }

    class DrawClock extends Thread {
        private boolean runFlag = false;
        private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
        private Bitmap picture;
        private Matrix matrix;
        private Paint painter;

        public DrawClock(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, Resources resources) {
            this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;

            picture = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources,
                    R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            matrix = new Matrix();
            this.painter = new Paint();
            this.painter.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            this.painter.setAntiAlias(true);
            this.painter.setFilterBitmap(true);
        }

        public void setRunning(boolean run) {
            runFlag = run;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Canvas canvas;
            while (runFlag) {


                matrix.preRotate(1.0f, picture.getWidth() / 2,
                        picture.getHeight() / 2);
                canvas = null;
                try {
                    canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                    synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                        canvas.drawColor(0, android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
                        canvas.drawBitmap(picture, matrix, this.painter);
                    }
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }  finally {
                    if (canvas != null) {
                        surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's work.

Comment: drawColor(0, android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR); thank you so much, i've been looking for this for hours!! i thought drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); will work.... but it didn't, your solution saved me..!

Comment: It didn't work for me. I have set the background of layout to be color #f0f0f0, but the background of surface view still remained black.

Comment: @Dmitry Nelepov: I tried the same code. but did not worked for me. The color of surfaceview still remains black.

Comment: i am getting just a black surface and nothing else , any help ?

Answer (score 3):

In API 3 and 4, you cannot put anything behind a `SurfaceView`. Quoting Dianne Hackborn:

> The surface view is actually BEHIND your window, and a hole punched in the window for you to see it.  You thus can put things on top of it in your window, but nothing in your window can appear behind it.

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/8d88ef9bb22da574

---

From API 5 onwards you can use `setZOrderOnTop`. The trick is that you have to do it in your constructor so it gets called before the view is attached to the window:

```
public ZenClockSurface(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
  super(context, attrs);

  setZOrderOnTop(true);

  SurfaceHolder holder = getHolder();
  holder.setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
}
```

Comment: I't not correct. Next changes in activity make SorfaceView transparent

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ZenClockSurface sfvTrack = (ZenClockSurface)findViewById(R.id.zenClockSurface1);
        sfvTrack.setZOrderOnTop(true);    // necessary
        SurfaceHolder sfhTrack = sfvTrack.getHolder();
        sfhTrack.setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    }

Comment: but i still have troubles, now then it turns - site where was picture is black.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out `setZOrderOnTop`, Rainwork! I've edited my answer. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: setZOrderOnTop - it's solve problem but not completly. Then image turns we have black "ghost" backgground. i answered to my questing, and give complete code, that works fine for me.

Comment: I suggest use setZOrderMediaOverlay(true); instead of setZOrderOnTop(true); because setZOrderMediaOverlay make it work like a regular view, which can be behind and above any view.